# Time plotting in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, plot

I have an array containing `[hour(24), minute, seconds, temperature]` and there are around 50,000 rows of this data.

I want to plot temperature against time. That is it. Sounds easy I know. I have tried playing with datetime.timedelta, datetime.strptime etc to no avail. I am using Ipython notebook and getting nowhere.

Comment: What code do you have already ? How do you load the data ? Is it a numpy array, a pandas array ?

Comment: `f = open('2GBDATALOG4.txt')`
`DATALOG4=np.zeros(0)`
`DATALOG4=f.read().split()`
`for i in range(0,len(DATALOG4)): DATALOG4[i]=DATALOG4[i].split(',')`
`UAV=np.array(DATALOG4).astype(float)`

sorry for the mess above, like I said it's my first time using this forum. I have other bits of code commented out but they don't work so no point showing that... Was hoping for a way forward rather than a correction of code that doesn't work. I don't have anything close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you can't plot `datetime.timedelta`s.  You'll need to make them a true `datetime.datetime` (or matplotlib's internal date representation).

There are several different ways to handle this.  If you're already using `pandas`, you can have it parse the three columns as a date. However, as you haven't mentioned `pandas`, I'll assume it's best not to rely on it.

Therefore, another to do this is to add in a date in addition to the time.  Which day doesn't matter, so we can use today, or Jan 1st, 1900, or whatever else you'd like.

For example:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    data = generate_data()
    hour, minute, sec, temp = data.T

    # For timedeltas, we need to convert to fractional seconds in a day
    seconds = hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + sec

    # Now we'll convert to "full" datetimes
    day = dt.datetime(2016, 01, 01)
    times = [day + dt.timedelta(0, second) for second in seconds]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot_date(times, temp, color='lightblue', linestyle='-', marker='')
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show()

def generate_data():
    """Generate data similar to yours."""
    num = 50000
    t = np.linspace(3, 22, num)
    minute = (t * 60) % 60
    second = (minute * 60) % 60
    hour = t.astype(int)
    minute = minute.astype(int)

    temp = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()

    data = np.column_stack([hour, minute, second, temp])
    return data

main()
```

[image]